# Как использовать Service для выполнения длительных закачек с сети?

Tags: android, android-service

Вопрос по поводу использования сервисов - есть необходимость выполнять длительные закачки с сети в фоне, независимо от того запущено приложение или нет. Собственно в самом приложении в реальном времени обновлять информацию о текущих закачках. По сути - обычный download менеджер. Как мне правильнее всего использовать сервис в таком случае - как Started Service или Bound Service? Закачек одновременных может быть несколько, соответственно есть нужда отображать о них инфу в приложении (если оно запущено).

Bound service - насколько я понимаю завершает свою работу если от него отсоединился последний компонент, можно управлять им в activity через созданный интерфейс. Но в этом то и вопрос - если процесс приложения уничтожается, то считается ли это "отсоединенным компонентом" от сервиса? И да, сервис выполняется в отдельном процессе.

Answer (score 2):

> Как мне правильнее всего использовать сервис в таком случае - как Started Service или Bound Service?

Ваш посыл неверен. Разница между *Started Service* и *Bound Service* только в том, в случае *Bound Service* вы получаете хэндлер/указатель на сервис, с которым вы что-то можете сделать (например следить за его выполнением или как то управлять выполнением). При отсоединении сервис продолжает свою работу, пока не получит сигнал на самоуничтожение.

Вам нужен `IntentService` - версия сервиса, который работает в отдельном потоке и поэтому не тормозит UI поток.

К вашему несчастью, `IntentService` при получении множества запросов выполняет их последовательно, то есть вы не сможете параллельно выполнять множество задач. Для параллелизации их выполнения (например одновременно несколько закачек) вам нужно следовать [инструкциям в документации](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#ExtendingIntentService) - создать свой `IntentService`, в котором разрешены параллельное выполнение, то есть `onStart()` создает свой тред и отрабатывает быстро и не задерживает  тред сервиса.

К счастью есть такая имплементация [ParallelIntentService](https://github.com/schoentoon/ParallelIntentService).

Answer (score 0):

Для длительных операций используйте: AsyncTask
Пример реализации Post запроса,где получаем ответ в data. У меня это конечно не downloader, но под свои нужды можете изменить.

```
  private static class SendLoginData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

     @Override
     protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
         try {
             String myURL = urls[0];
             String request = urls[1];
             byte[] data;
             InputStream is;
             try {
                 URL url = new URL(myURL);
                 HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                 conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                 conn.setDoOutput(true);
                 conn.setDoInput(true);
                 conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + Integer.toString(request.getBytes().length));
                 OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
                 data = request.getBytes("UTF-8");
                 os.write(data);
                 conn.connect();
                 int responseCode= conn.getResponseCode();
                 ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                 if (responseCode == 200) {
                     is = conn.getInputStream();
                     byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
                     int bytesRead;
                     while ((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                         baos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                     }
                     data = baos.toByteArray();
                     return new String(data, "UTF-8");
                 }
             } catch (Exception ignored) {}
         } catch (Exception ignored) {}
         return null;
     }
 }
```

Если нужно общение с пользователем во время работы, то вот примерная схема:

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Integer> {
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
    // [... Обновите индикатор хода выполнения, уведомления или другой   
    // элемент пользовательского интерфейса ...]
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Integer... result) {
    // [... Сообщите о результате через обновление пользовательского 
    // интерфейса, диалоговое окно или уведомление ...]
}
@Override
protected Integer doInBackground(String... parameter) {
    int myProgress = 0;
    // [... Выполните задачу в фоновом режиме, обновите переменную myProgress...]
    publishProgress(myProgress);
    // [... Продолжение выполнения фоновой задачи ...]
    // Верните значение, ранее переданное в метод onPostExecute
    return result;
}
}
```